# Nginx multi website multi public ip

Tags: nginx, proxy, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I have deployed platform with archetecture where I have nginx lb server hash, behind is app server that has 4 apps. nginx lb server has configurations such as:

upstream example1.com {
    ip_hash;
    server 10.10.10.10;
    server 10.10.20.10
}

upstream example2.com {
    ip_hash;
    server 10.10.10.11;
    server 10.10.20.11
}

So it proxies to servers with private ip's. My question is how can each of this apps get dedicated public ip address? My proxy server has 4 ip addresses and I want to point each address to each app.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify this a little? How many nginx servers do you have? How many app servers do you have. From the question at the moment I would guess, 1 nginx server and 2 app servers is that correct?

Comment: There is one nginx server in public subent and 4 nginx with app servers in private subent. In nginx server that is public there is a file in /etc/nginx/sites-enable eg /etc/nginx/sites-enable/example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enable/test.com I want each of this sites to have it's own public IP

Comment: It would be helpful to see the rest of the sites config for the nginx server in the public subnet, and also an ifconfig for the public nginx server

Comment: Well config for a front end is in question:upstream example1.com { ip_hash; server 10.10.10.10; server 10.10.20.10 }

upstream example2.com { ip_hash; server 10.10.10.11; server 10.10.20.11 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you are asking for

create the following file /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain1.com with the following contents

```
upstream backend1 {
ip_hash;

server 10.10.10.10;
server 10.10.20.10;
}

server {
    listen    1.1.1.1:80;
    listen    1.1.1.2:80;
    server_name    www.domain1.com;

location / {  
        proxy_pass http://backend1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    
    }
}
```

Then make a second file /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain2.com

```
upstream backend2 {
ip_hash;

server 10.10.10.11;
server 10.10.20.11;
}

server {
    listen    1.1.1.3:80;
    listen    1.1.1.4:80;
    server_name    www.domain2.com;

location / {  
        proxy_pass http://backend2;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    
    }
}
```

Then do ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain* /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/